# Why doesn't fortran iterate over strings

Tags: arrays, string, fortran, gfortran

When I declare a string like:

```
character(19) :: line 
do I = 1, 19, 1 
if (line(I) == 'n')
```

the compiler tells me about an error. How to fix this?
When I declare like this:

```
character line(19)
```

I have no problems with -if, but then I have to press enter after every character I want to put in my string.

Comment: Which erreor? You should always include the error messages into your questions.

Comment: Yes. Two answers have looked at the substring reference, but the `if` statement/construct is also broken.  One addresses that, as well.  It depends what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You have two quite different things.

```
character(19) line
```

declares a scalar character variable of length 19, whereas

```
character line(19)
```

declares a rank-1 array of size 19 of character variables of length 1.

`line(i)` is the syntax to reference element `i` of the array `line`.  This is valid only when `line` is an array (your second, working, case).  As can be seen in Fortran 2008 6.4.1 a substring, even of length one, is referenced using a different syntax.  In your case `line(i:i)`.

For the array

```
character(19) lines(2)
```

we can have access like `lines(1)(1:1)` whereas `lines(1)` would be the length-19 first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
character(10) :: line
do i =1, 10
if( line(i:i) == 'n') then
...
```